# Mixing Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 projects in Visual Studio 2012 solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a solution which has 8 projects, all of them were created in Visual Studio 2010 (solution and projects). Now, we're using Visual Studio 2012, and all them of can be opened and used in VS 2010 and 2012, and this is nice.

But, I created a new solution and a new project in VS 2012, and added all projects from the old solution in this new solution. So, now I have a new solution created in VS 2012 which have 1 project created in VS 2012 and 8 projects created in VS 2010.

Now I'm having problems with this new solution. Sometimes the Visual Studio 2012 crashes, randomly, during solution loading, during build, during debug, before run.

Should I recreate all old projects in VS2012 and avoid to mix projects versions inside a solution created in VS 2012 ?

**SCREEN SHOTS:**

Sometimes crashes with this window (collection information...):

[image]

And other times, crashes with this window (just checking for solution):

[image]

All times no solution is found, and is just restarted:

[image]

Comment: What kind of errors are you receiving?

Comment: It just crashes. A message box is shown saying that some problem was detected, and the VS 2012 is closed and restarted. Sometimes the problem occurs several times in a row, others doesn't occur for several hours. If I get it again I'll try to take a screenshot and post it here.

Answer (score 2):

There is a known issue under investigation where Visual Studio 2012 randomly crashes after installing KB2781514 for certain installations. If you have it installed, try uninstalling it to see whether this fixes it.

Try disabling all add-ins and extensions to see whether any of them is causing this behavior. VS2010 and 2012 should be mutually compatible as long as you don't add a 4.5 project (which VS2010 can't handle).

If the problem persists, open a ticket on [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) or use the [feedback client](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2012/09/08/are-you-reporting-visual-studio-2012-issues-to-microsoft-correctly.aspx) and [upload a minidump](http://blogs.msdn.com/debugger/archive/2009/12/30/what-is-a-dump-and-how-do-i-create-one.aspx) or a [crash report bucketid](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYu6snQWTn8). The product team will look into your issues.

Comment: My new project created in VS 2012 is using framework 4.5, but I don't need to open this project neither the solution in VS 2010. Well, could it add instabilities ? Should I try to use 4.0 instead ?

Comment: No, this is fine. The crashes should not be caused by mixing platforms.